# How to fix net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, vps

I created a full stack website (Spring boot rest API + Angular front end) and uploaded my angular files along with the spring boot jar file into filemanager.

The front end works fine, however the spring boot backend connection is refused even after starting the jar file from ssh terminal. The angular front end is not able to consume the API Services and the page throws error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/conversion' from origin 'Here it shows my URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.
```

GET http://localhost:8000/conversion net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

When I run the API from eclipse and start the website from visual Studio I open the website locally (localhost:4200) and everything works fine, not errors and the API services are consumed correctly by the angular front end. The issue happens once I deploy the application in the VPS server.

Front end is simply not able to connect to the spring boot backend. I've done some research but I have not found anything related to this specific issue.

How can I make this work?

Comment: The error talks about `localhost:8000`, but when you open the site locally you use `localhost:4200`?

Comment: My spring boot uses localhost:8000 and angular by default uses localhost:4200, I added @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") in my spring boot controller and everything works fine in development environment. As soon as I move my angular files and spring boot jar file to production environment (VPS server) angular front end works but cannot connect to spring boot.

Comment: It was a simple fix, that I guess it was more like common sense, I just could not see at first and I could not find an answer online. I ended up replacing @CrossOrigin(origins = "localhost:4200") by @CrossOrigin(origins = "www.MYDOMAIN.com") and that fixed it. Now angular and spring boot are communicating correctly in the VPS server.

Comment: I ended up replacing @CrossOrigin(origins = "localhost:4200") by @CrossOrigin(origins = "www.MYDOMAIN.com") and that fixed it. Now angular and spring boot are communicating correctly in the VPS server.